# How to import a specific project from github

Tags: eclipse, github

How to import a specific project from github ? I dont want to clone the entire repository 
I just want to clone only a portion of repository .

For eg this url https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials
has many projects but I just want to clone only spring-boot-crud project .
Here is the url for spring-boot-crud project.
https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot-modules/spring-boot-crud

Thank you .

Comment: I have edited my answer to include an example with Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

You can look into a [`git sparse-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout): that command is made to checkout only part of a Git repository. This assume the latest Git 2.26 though.
And I mean Git-core, as in [Git SCM](https://git-scm.com/download/), not [Egit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/) (which does not support the new `sparse-checkout` command)

Even though the command is new and still experimental, it should be useful in your case.

```
git clone --no-checkout /url/a/repo
cd repo
git sparse-checkout init --cone
git sparse-checkout set spring-boot-modules/spring-boot-crud
```

Then open the relevant project in your Eclipse.

Create a project in the Git repo (`.project`, in the root folder of your repo)

That will give you:

```
git clone -n https://github/git/git git2
cd git2
git sparse-checkout init
git sparse-checkout set Documentation
```

At this point, you have the repository [`git/git`](https://github.com/git/git) with *only* the folder `Documentation` checked out (everything else is not in the working tree)

```
# create an empty project in C:\path\to\git2 in Eclipse
```

[image: Sparsed-checkout repo in Eclipse]

As you can see, all the other files not checked out are not displayed in the Git staging view. Only the ones currently checked out and modified are listed.

The first step must be done in command-line because JGit does not support the sparse-checkout directive (see [but 383772](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383772) and [change 33](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/110964/33))

Comment: This clones the entire repository and checks out one folder only, right? With the *latest Git* you mean git-core (the command line Git), not EGit, right? Please make it clearer that you are talking about a different tool than what was asked for. Have you tested if both tools work together this way (show history, commit, push, etc.)?

Comment: @howlger Yes, git-core. Once the working tree is correctly populated, you can open the project within Eclipse.

Comment: Nice. What about the not checked out files? In the _Git Staging_ view will they be shown as deleted or just be ignored?

Comment: @howlger Not sure. Even JGit does not seem to support sparse checkout: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383772 and https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/110964/33

Comment: @howlger I just tested it with an Eclipse 2020-03/JDK14/Git 2.26.2: the sparsed checked out repo is not detected when I try an Import project Git.

Comment: @howlger Never mind, I had a hard time importing that Git (sparse-checkout) repo into Eclipse, but it actually works! See my edited answer for an example of the Git Staging view.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the bug report. Good to know that it already works with git-core. I hope EGit/JGit will soon support a `sparse-checkout` (a proposal  for a implementation already exists).